# How to formalize pretend rate functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Say we have the graph of some exact but unknown rate of change function, $r_h(x)$. It is some curve on $(a,b)$.
The "pretend rate" function is the curve that approximates $r_h(x)$. Let's say the approximated curve is $r(x)$.

Specifically, we partition $(a,b)$ into $n$ subintervals of equal width $\Delta x$ -- and then draw horizontal line segments of with $\Delta x$ throughout the entire interval. From the left endpoints of one line segment to the next, we draw a line that connects them to approximate the curve $r_h(x)$. Doing this throughout the entire interval gives us a sketch of the curve we're approximating.

My issue is I'm not sure how to formalize that process in a cleaner way (the process being using sequence of constant rates to approximate a changing rate of change).

My attempt has been defining $r(x)$ as the following: $$\cfrac{r_h(a+x\Delta x)-r_h(a+(x-1)\Delta x)}{\Delta x}(x-a)$$

However, I tested this out many times and it doesn't quite work well at all, especially as $n$ grows.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking a numerical derivative.  The problem is that any errors in measurement are amplified by the division by $\Delta x$, which becomes very small.  If you have values for the function at equally spaced points it is better to find the Fourier expansion of your function.  You may have reason to believe there should not be any content above some frequency, like an amplifier with a bandwidth limit.  You can then throw away those Fourier components and take the derivative of what is left analytically.  That will be much more stable.  Note that the derivative of $\sin (kx)$ is $k \cos (kx)$ so the short wavelengths (high frequencies) are accentuated by taking a derivative.